Are localic maps monotonic?
A frame homomorphism $f:L\to M$ is increasing which means that if $l_1 \le l_2$ then $f(l_1)\le f(l_2)$.
What about the corresponding localic map $\tilde f :M\to L$ is it increasing?
All what we know is that $f$ and $\tilde f$ are adjoint so they are related by this relation
$$f(l)\le m \Leftrightarrow  l\le \tilde f(m)$$
So if we are given $m_1 \le m_2$, set $l_1=\tilde f(m_1)$ and $l_2=\tilde f(m_2)$ we can deduce from the adjunction relation that $f(l_2)\ge m_2\ge m_1$ but $f(l_1)$ can be anywhere with respect to $f(l_2)$ we only know that $f(l_1) \ge m_1$.

What do you mean for a locale map to be "increasing"? Do you want it to preserve the specialization order on (generalized) points? Edit: Oh, actually, reading your question more carefully it looks like you want to know that the direct image part of $f$ (moving in the localic direction, but considered a map of frames) is monotone. Is that what you mean? Because that's true, and I can leave an answer ^_^

yes exactly that's what I meant. please leave an answer.

The main insight I think you're missing is that a function between (semi)lattices that preserves joins (or meets) is automatically monotone! This is because the order structure can be defined in terms of the joins (or meets) as
$x \leq y \iff x \lor y = y \ \ ( \!\iff x \land y = x)$. So if $f : A \to B$ preserves joins then whenever $x \leq y$ we have $x \lor y = y$, so $f(x) \lor f(y) = f(y)$ since $f$ preserves joins, and thus $f(x) \leq f(y)$. I'll leave it to you to modify this argument to show that a function preserving meets is also automatically monotone.
The second main insight I think you're missing (which is likely to take more time to develop) is how to use category theory to solve these kinds of "formal" problems for you!

First let's see how to solve this without category theory:
Let's say that $f^* : L \to M$ is a frame homomorphism. That is, a function preserving all joins and finite meets. Then we can build the right adjoint $f_* : M \to L$ as $f_*(m) = \bigvee \{ l \mid f^*(l) \leq m \}$, which exists since frames have all joins. Now with this explicit definition, we can check
$$
\begin{align}
f_*(m_1 \land m_2) 
&= \bigvee \{ l \mid f^*(l) \leq (m_1 \land m_2) \} \\
&= \bigvee \{ l \mid f^*(l) \leq m_1 \text{ and } f^*(l) \leq m_2 \} \\
&= \left ( \bigvee \{ l \mid f^*(l) \leq m_1 \} \right ) \land \left ( \bigvee \{ l \mid f^*(l) \leq m_2 \} \right ) \\
&= f_*(m_1) \land f_*(m_2)
\end{align}
$$
So $f_*$ preserves finite meets, so is monotone by the earlier discussion.

But this argument is "purely formal" and works in a variety of settings. So category theorists have abstracted it into a single theorem we can cite in all these situations! With some category theory, we can give an argument like this:
Viewing $L$ and $M$ as poset categories, monotone maps are functors, joins are colimits, and meets are limits. So a frame map $f^* : L \to M$ is a functor preserving all colimits (and finite limits). But by the adjoint functor theorem $f^*$ must have a right adjoint functor $f_* : M \to L$. In particular, $f_*$ is a functor, so is monotone!
If you consult the (constructive!) proof of the adjoint functor theorem, you'll find that the $f_*$ it builds is exactly the $f_*$ from the previous section. Moreover, if you consult the part of the proof that $f_*$ preserves all limits, you'll find an argument similar to the explicit argument given above showing $f_*$ preserves meets. So if you like, this category theoretic proof actually "compiles down" to basically the same explicit proof we gave above!

As one last note, I'll remark that frame homomorphisms preserving "all limits and finite colimits" might sound familiar if you've ever thought about topos theory. Indeed the theory of frames is in many many ways similar to the theory of (grothendieck) topoi, and this is one reflection of that. Indeed, the category theoretic argument goes through entirely unchanged to show that a geometric morphism $f^* : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}$ of topoi must have a right adjoint functor moving in the "geometric direction" $f_* : \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{F}$.

I hope this helps ^_^
